# Mapping two data sets in Perl

Tags: perl, parsing, mapping, analysis

I have a data set which has a list of user agents and devices corresponding to those UAs. There is another data set that has other data along with the User Agents. I need a way to identify the devices in that data.

So, I'll have to map the UAs in the two files and then get the corresponding device info from the file that has the list. I've gotten as far as making a list of UAs in a hash from the first file and matching this with the UA in the data file. How do I get the corresponding information from the first file that has the device info again and write it to a file?

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use warnings;
use strict;

our $inputfile = $ARGV[0];
our $outputfile = "$inputfile" . '.devidx';
our $devid_file = "devid_master";  # the file that has the UA and the corresponding device info
our %ua_list_hash = ();

# Create a list of mobile user agents in the devid_master file
 open DEVID, "$devid_file" or die "can't open $devid_file";

 while(<DEVID>) {
        chomp;
        my @devidfile = split /\t/;
        $ua_list_hash{$devidfile[1]} = 0;
 }  

 open IN,"$inputfile" or die "can't open $inputfile";       
 while(<IN>) {      
       chomp;       
       my @hhfile = split /\t/;       

       if(exists $ua_list_hash{$hhfile[24]}) {     
                     # how do I get the rest of the columns from the devidfile, columns 2...10?
       }
 }

 close IN;
```

Or is there a better way to do this is Perl? That is always welcome :).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When building the first lookup hash, couldn't you store a reference to the other column data as the hash value, rather than just 0?

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use warnings;
use strict;

our $inputfile = $ARGV[0];
our $outputfile = "$inputfile" . '.devidx';
our $devid_file = "devid_master";  # the file that has the UA and the corresponding device info
our %ua_list_hash = ();

# Create a list of mobile user agents in the devid_master file
 open DEVID, "$devid_file" or die "can't open $devid_file";
 while(<DEVID>) {
        chomp;
        my @devidfile = split /\t/;
        # save the columns you'll want to access later and
        # store a reference to them as the hash value
        my @values = @devidfile[2..$#devidfile];   
        $ua_list_hash{$devidfile[1]} = \@values;
 }  

 open IN,"$inputfile" or die "can't open $inputfile";       
 while(<IN>) {      
       chomp;       
       my @hhfile = split /\t/;       

       if(exists $ua_list_hash{$hhfile[24]}) {
           my @rest_of_vals = @{$ua_list_hash{$hhfile[24]};
           # do something with @rest_of_vals
       }
 }

 close IN;
```

Note: I've not tested this.

Comment: yup that works :), thats the problem of being not to well versed in Perl. Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

What do you want your output to look like? A list of all the unique devices occurring in the $inputfile. Or for every line in the $inputfile, output a line displaying which device it is?

I'll answer the latter, since you can do a unique sort on it if needed. Also, looks like each UA has multiple devices. As a general approach, you can store the UA names as keys in your hash and the value could be either an array of device names or a character-delimited string of device names.

If you know the device names are elements 2..10 you can use the slice and join operators to construct, for example, a comma-delimited string of device names. This string will be the value assigned to the UA name key.

```
  #!/usr/bin/perl

    use warnings;
    use strict;

    our $inputfile = $ARGV[0];
    our $outputfile = "$inputfile" . '.devidx';
    our $devid_file = "devid_master";  # the file that has the UA and the corresponding device info
    our %ua_list_hash = ();

    # Create a list of mobile user agents in the devid_master file
     open DEVID, "$devid_file" or die "can't open $devid_file";

     while(<DEVID>) {
            chomp;
            my @devidfile = split /\t/;
            my @slice = @devidfile[2..10];
            my $deviceString = join(",", @slice);
            $ua_list_hash{$devidfile[1]} = $deviceString;
     }  

     my $outputfilename = "output.txt";
     open IN,"$inputfile" or die "can't open $inputfile";
     open OUT,"$outputfilename" or die "can't open $outputfilename";       
     while(<IN>) {      
           chomp;       
           my @hhfile = split /\t/;       

           if(exists $ua_list_hash{$hhfile[24]}) {     
               print OUT $ua_list_hash{$hhfile[24]}."\n";   

           }
     }

 close IN;
 close OUT;
```